# SourceTree 2 - How to change install directory on Windows

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

By default, SourceTree 2.x installs silently and chooses to sit in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\SourceTree` directory.

Forefully moving it does not break it, but updater does not work correctly - still, seeking version in old location, and various tools it is trying to launch from original location.

I don't want it to sit in `C:\*`, but in `E:\`, I don't want its settings to sit somewhere deep in `C:\*`, I want it to be compact and understandable, but it seems that new version [2.x] does not allow us to change anything.

What needs to be done to:

- install it in specific directory;
- move from one location to another without breaking its access to its tools and updater;
- change the location of options\settings?

Answer (score 4):

Use the Enterprise Installer
https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/enterprise
This lets you pick the installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

Still not possible.
The issue is created in the bugtracker, but the priority is set to low.
See: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-7168

Comment: Thank you for referencing that issue

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only solution to this is to install a version prior to 2.0. You can find the link to the latest 1.9 version here:

https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/update/windowsupdates.txt